# SQL: Where not exits - insert only if not exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to Insert the values only if they are not already exits. My table is called `wp_all_import`and my values called `pid`, `price`, `price_old`, `shop`and `link`.

Can anybody please tell me whats wrong here?
Because he inserts the values nevertheless they exits already...

```
INSERT INTO `wp_all_import` ('$pid', '$price', '$price_old', '$link', '$shop') 
        SELECT 'pid', 'price', 'price_old', 'shop', 'link' FROM `wp_all_import` 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `wp_all_import` 
        WHERE (pid = '$rpid') AND (price = '$rprice') AND (price_old = '$rprice_old') AND (shop = '$rshop') AND (link = '$rlink'))
```

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: Aren't you sure the problem isn't that you are using single quote `'` instead of double quotes `"`? It is taken as a literal with single quotes.

Comment: Plus why are you using different variables for the same field, as in `$pid` and `$rpid`?

Comment: Now I see that. The variables should all be with an r before the name...
But this is still not fixing my problem...

Comment: 1. do you want to insert from select or values (`$id`)? you can't do both. 2. you can't `INSERT ... WHERE`. It does not make sense. You insert into a table, and you either specify id's, or an auto-increment decides it. 3. `WHERE NOT EXISTS` is a condition for searches, for inserts you would use `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` or `ON DUPLICATE` nothing. 4.OMG sql injection, please learn about parameterized queries, right now, before coding anything else. If you have code in production you owe it to your users to fix that before adding any new feature.

Comment: 6. do you have error reporting? that query is wrong, it will not even run. You should be receiving error messages. If not, enable error reporting. If you do receive, please read them and address what they say.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't really understood your code but i think this is what you are looking for:

i considered that variables *(starting with $ sign)* represents the values you want to insert

```
INSERT INTO wp_all_import(pid, price, price_old, shop, link)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT $pid, $price, $price_old, $shop, $link) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM wp_all_import 
    WHERE pid= $pid AND price = $price 
    AND price_old = $price_old AND link = $link
    AND shop = $shop) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: What is name by select?

Comment: @Jan it was a mistake updated my answer

Comment: Okay, Thank you. I will try it. But my variables are called with an r before. So I change that and will test it :D

Comment: Saddly it is not working... `$sql = "INSERT INTO wp_all_import(pid, price, price_old, shop, link)
   SELECT * FROM (SELECT '$pid', '$price', '$price_old', '$shop', '$link') AS tmp
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT * FROM wp_all_import 
      WHERE pid = '$pid' AND price = '$price' 
      AND price_old = '$price_old' AND link = '$link'
      AND shop = '$shop') LIMIT 1";`